# Ошибка вызова класса mysqli внутри Zend FrameWork 3

Tags: mysqli, zend-framework-3

Контроллер:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use Application\Common\CommonServices;
use Application\Common\MySQL;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController{        
    var $sqln; 
    public function __construct() {        
       $this->$sqln=new MySQL();
           $this->$sqln->connect("localhost",'root','ввв','222');
     }
```

Класс работы с MySQL:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Common;
class MySQL {
    var $idsqlconnection;
    var $query_result;
    var $num_queries = 0;
    function connect($host, $name, $pass, $base,$codemysql="utf8"){        
        $this->idsqlconnection = new mysqli($host, $name, $pass, $base);
...
```

При вызове из __construct() команды $this->$sqln->connect("localhost",'root','ввв','222');, Zend Framework 3 вываливается с ошибкой:

```
Error

File:

    /var/www/webuseorg4/module/Application/src/Common/MySQL.php:22

Message:

    Class 'Application\Common\mysqli' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае Mysqli находится в другом пространстве имен, поэтому его нужно вызывать от "корня": new \mysqli($host, $name, $pass, $base);